# How to calculate the response time with M/M/c/PS(Processor Sharing) models in queueing theory?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, queueing-theory

I'm trying to model the process scheduling mechanism in Linux using queueing theory models.

Assuming that both the arrival and processing times of processes in the system follow a Poisson distribution of, and the system contains `c` independent logical cores, this scenario approximates an `M/M/c` model.

The challenge, however, is that this model assumes each task is executed sequentially in a first-come-first-served manner to completion. In practice, Linux uses a Round-robin scheduling scheme (not considering the impact of the Completely Fair Scheduler). That is, the system sets a time slice, assumed to be of length `s`, where the continuous execution time of a task does not exceed the time slice length s. If a task's execution time surpasses `s` before completion, it is interrupted and placed back at the end of the waiting queue.

Given this context, how should I calculate the average waiting time for each process?

---

Now I know that this scenario can be approximated through a ["processor sharing" model](https://www.netlab.tkk.fi/opetus/s383141/kalvot/E_psjono.pdf), but the PS models in the relevant materials are all based on the assumption of M/M/1. **How can we extend them to the multi processor scenario of M/M/c?**

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.